# Help with a simple logical negation: NOT $\forall \epsilon > 0 (\exists a\in S \text{ s.t. } x-\epsilon < a)$

Tags: logic

Reading the above out in plain English sounds like:

" for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists some number $a\in S$ which satisfies $x-\epsilon < a$. "

Now, just using simple English language skills, I had assumed that the negation of this would be something like

" for all $\epsilon>0$, there is no member $a$ of $S$ which satisfies $x-\epsilon < a$,"

therefore (according to me),

"for all $\epsilon>0$, every member $a$ of $S$ satisfies $x-\epsilon \geq a$."

In math speak, this is

$\forall (\epsilon > 0, a\in S) (x-\epsilon\geq a)$.

This makes sense to me on a basic level. I've been told, however, that the correct negation is

$\forall \epsilon>0 (\exists a\in S\text{ s.t. } (x-\epsilon \geq a))$.

Call me silly but I don't understand that. I accept that it is a true statement, but I do not understand why it is not stronger. I am looking for a little intuitive guidance - thank you!

Comment: The negation of $\forall x ~.~ P(x)$ is $\exists x ~.~ \neg P(x)$.  If it is not true that $P$ is true for all $x$, then there exists an $x$ such that $P$ is false of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your negation is wrong. It should in fact be,

$\exists \epsilon > 0$ such that $\forall a \in S, x - \epsilon \geq a$.

Some intuition as to why:

$\forall$ always negates to $\exists$ because if a statement is supposed to be true *for all*, then it only takes one object defying it (there exists) for the statement to be false.

$\exists$ always negates to $\forall$ because if there only has to be one object satisfying a condition, we must have that *everything* defies the condition in order for it to be false.

I hope that makes sense, feel free to ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the negation should be $\exists \epsilon>0(\forall a \in S, x-\epsilon\geq a) $. Which might help you with your confusion.